# Одна из 99999 тем о старте новичка в программировании

Tags: python

я прошел курсы https://stepik.org/course/58852/promo и https://stepik.org/course/68343/promo, но не знаю куда и как двигаться дальше.

Цель: устроится разработчиком на Python через год ( скопил денег, уволился с работы ).

Посоветуйте учебники с актуальной информацией ( прочитал 1 том Изучаем питон Марка Лутца, на мой взгляд это была пустая трата времени т.к. не актуальная информация ).

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135068/discussion-on-question-by-agent-007---99999------).

Answer (score 2):

> Цель: устроится разработчиком на Python через год

Вот из этого и нужно исходить.

- Открываете какой-нибудь сайт с актуальными вакансиями.
- Отбираете те из них, которые вам подходят по деньгам и другим условиям (удалёнка/офис, время начала работы и прочее).
- Смотрите, что требуется знать на этих вакансиях (раздел "требования").
- Лезете в гугль и ютьюб, ищете там таториалы и доки по этим темам, изучаете их.
- Профит.

Но в общем полезно и задачки на специальных сайтах поделать и просто общие обучающие видео по питону посмотреть. Но цель должна быть устроиться на конкретные вакансии, а для этого изучить конкретные понятия и библиотеки языка.

И нужно помнить, что без предыдущего опыта работы по профилю вас скорее всего возьмут только на junior позиции. И есть ещё вариант позиция стажёра, платят там очень мало, но зато можно получить опыт реальной работы.

Comment: Спасибо, отличная идея